# Unable to access limited access folder from Windows 7 PC

Tags: samba, authentication

I am a complete novice at Ubuntu and Linux systems in general.  I have wanted to play around with the OS for years and finally set up a spare computer and installed Ubuntu 12.04.2.  My goal is to make this machine a simple file sharing pc for my family to share all the music/videos/pictures on one machine. I have installed Samba with Samba Server Configuration.

I successfully shared the Photo/Music/Video folders on the Ubuntu pc and can access it on the Windows PC's in the house.  When I set up the share options, I set access to everyone and everyone can get get access to them. No problem, so far so good.

I created a Storage folder to backup some important documents and files that I don't want the kids to have access too.  When I set it up with Everyone access, I can get to the folder on my Windows 7 pc with no problems.  When I set it up with specific users, I get prompted by Windows to enter user name and password; and when I enter the correct credentials, I get an error.

How can I put password protection on the shared folder so only I can get access?

Comment: your samba process and your folder should be same user space.

Comment: Have you added a samba user with a `smbpasswd` on your ubuntu?